# Spring - Share UserDetailsService across WebMVC & Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm implementing a web application with some basic login mechanism using Spring & Spring Security. All fine, but I'm facing a question (maybe it's not a problem, let's see).

My WebApp is structured like this (No XML Config, Servlet-3.0 and Spring 4.0):

**WebAppInitializer**
Intention: Configure WebApplication

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    applicationContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    applicationContext.refresh();

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(Dispatcher);
    context.setParent(applicationContext);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher-servlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
  }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**
Intention: Add Security

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
  public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
  }
}
```

There are also classes:

- AppConfig (@Configuration, @ComponentScan for xyz.services)
- DispatcherConfig (@Configuration, @EnableWebMVc and @ComponentScan for xyz.controller)
- SecurityConfig (@Configuration, @EnableWebSecurity, @ComponentScan for xyz.services)
- CustomerUserDetailsService implementing UserDetailsService (@Service)

**My problem/question:**
I want to use the * CustomerUserDetailsService* in Security for the *AuthenticationManagerBuilder*  and in my controllers - is there a way to have only one instance of the UserDetailsService? In this configuration it will create two instances: one for the Application Context and one for the Security Context. Did I miss anything in the configuration? Or is this the favourite way to have it configured?

Another question beside that is: is there any way to use this configuration supporting @Secured annotation on my controller? There was no way to get this working.

Comment: Hi, you can write own User AuthenticationProvider and configure in your SecurityConfig class.

Comment: Why not use dependency injection? @Autowired CustomerUserDetailsService cuds;

Comment: I'm using @Autowired for the Services. The problem is not the wiring, that works very well. The confusing point is the fact that I need to add it to both configurations: WebMvc and Security, which in fact means: it will create two classes and not use one shared singleton across the whole application.